# encfs error on OS X 10.9.4

Tags: macos, unix, encryption, osx-mavericks, fuse

I installed encfs and osxfuse through homebrew. 
Unfortunately when I try to call encfs I get this error:

```
dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/gettext/lib/libintl.8.dylib
  Referenced from: /usr/local/bin/encfs
  Reason: image not found
Trace/BPT trap: 5
```

My unix skills are rather novice so I don't even know where to start with this.
Any help is appreciated!

Thanks
Nick

Answer (score 3):

Well,

```
brew install gettext
```

fixed it.